# How to draw a Sprite with Touch Points in LibGDX

Tags: android, libgdx

I want to draw some path with user's touch. if users moves finger from one position to another position a path will be drawn exactly as user moved finger.

We can draw a line with by defining color but i want to draw that line with sprite. i want to use image for that. is it possible with LibGDX? if yes , how we do that? and how will i generate image to use as sprite for that?